# Confusion regarding the composition of homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

The textbook that I have been using to learn group theory asked, as an exercise, to prove the following:

[image: Initial Exercise]

The proof is straightforward. However, what has me confused is the following remark that the author makes after the exercise has been completed:

[image: Author Remark]

My understanding of an *endomorphism* is a homomorphic mapping of a group to itself (i.e. $f: G \rightarrow G)$. In the case of what we were asked to prove, the mappings were between different groups; consequently, I am unsure of why this proof motivated (or served as a convenient segue for) these remarks. I fail to see the relationship between what I proved and the subsequent commentary.

Any explanation would be appreciated!

Comment: No, what is being said is not really all that tied to the proposition. It's just saying that the collection of endomorphisms of a group forms a monoid, and the collection of automorphisms forms a group.

Comment: If we let $G=H=M$, we've shown in the proposition that the composition of two endomorphisms is an endomorphism, so since we have an identity endomorphism (and the composition of functions is associative), we have a monoid. If the endomorphisms are automorphisms then we have inverses, which then gives us the group $\text{Aut}(G)$

Comment: @Dave That should be an answer ...

Answer (score 2):

If we let $G=H=M$, we've shown in the proposition that the composition of two endomorphisms $f,g:G\to G$ is an endomorphism, so since we have an identity endomorphism (and the composition of functions is associative), we have a monoid. If the endomorphisms are automorphisms then we have inverses, which then gives us the group $\text{Aut}(G)$.

Comment: what do you mean by "since we have an identity endomorphism"? Are you just saying that, "given the collection of all endomorphisms, there is certainly an 'identity endomorphism' that belongs to this collection"?

Comment: Yes that's all I meant, the identity map $\text{Id}_G:G\to G$ is definitely an endomorphism, and for any endomorphism $f$ we have that $f\circ\text{Id}_G=\text{Id}_G\circ f=f$. It's one of the requirements of a monoid that we have an identity element, they're like groups but without the requirement that we have inverses.

Comment: okay...I'm getting a feeling for what you (and the author) are saying. My only confusion is, if we are referring to the collection of endomorphisms as a monoid...that means that we are treating these endomorphisms as a group. Where exactly do binary operations come in to play? (because every group also has a corresponding binary operation). Would it be, for example, "one endomorphism + another endomorphism"...in which case, the binary operation is "Addition"?

Comment: The binary operation is the composition of functions, so if $E$ is the set of endomorphisms, we can define the monoid $(E,\star)$ where, for endomorphisms $f,g\in E$, we set $f\star g=g\circ f$, which your textbook just writes as $gf$. This is the standard composition of functions, so for $a\in G$ we have $g\circ f(a)=g(f(a))$. Associativity then follows because the composition of two functions is associative, regardless of if they're endomorphisms or not.

Comment: This is why if we look at automorphisms, we get a group instead of just a monoid. An automorphism $f$ has an inverse $f^{-1}$, with $f\circ f^{-1}=f^{-1}\circ f=\text{Id}_G$.